# Database guide on how to store cancelled transaction

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm developing a simple POS system and all works well until one day, my boss ask me to add 'cancel' button. The function of cancel is to cancel the POS transaction.

The requirement is simple,

1. Cancel by receipt no (POSID) - the whole items in that receipt will be cancelled (no partial cancellation)
2. Need history of who, why and when the cancellation was made.

I read about 'double entry', but I still can't figure out how to implement it in my current table structure. The following is my current table structure:

POSSales

```
----------------------------------
| ID   | PaymentID   | Amount    |
----------------------------------
| 360  | 27676       | 77.10     |
| 361  | 27680       | 11.50     |
----------------------------------
```

POSDetails

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID   | POSID   | ItemID  | Quantity | Amount   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1212 | 360     | 6       | 1        |  7.10    |
| 1213 | 360     | 10      | 2        | 50.00    |
| 1214 | 360     | 12      | 1        | 20.00    |
| 1215 | 361     | 4       | 1        | 11.50    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Payment

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID   | DatePayment | PaymentType | Amount  | Reference | Remarks  | CreatedBy |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 27676| 2019-09-01  | 1           | 77.10   | null       | null    | 122       |
| 27680| 2019-09-02  | 3           | 11.50   | 124578     | null    | 122       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying not to add a new column. If I have to, then I will do. It's just that I need to update other things if I add a new column here.

But before that, can anybody suggest if I can use the current table structure to cater for cancelled transaction?

Answer (score 0):

For #1, you can add an another `VARCHAR(1)` column in POSSales table with possible values 'Y' or 'N' to signify that the certain POSID is valid or already cancelled. Initially set it to 'Y' to signify that the payment is still valid.

For #2, you can add 3 columns in POSSales table for who cancelled `(VARCHAR OR INT)`, why it was cancelled `(TEXT)`, as well as the cancel datetime `(TIMESTAMP)`. Set the 3 columns' value to `NULL` initially.

Comment: thanks but I still don't get it.. 
For #1 .. add column like Status? So Status of the POS.. Cancelled (N) or Valid (Y)?
Then add 3 additional column to store who cancelled, why and when in table POSSales?

Can you explain further?

Im thinking to use the Payment table to store DatePayment as DateCancelled, Reference as the POSID, Remarks as why cancelled and CreatedBy as Who cancelled.. 

Its just that Im not sure how to link it back.. and i need to check reference column for each payment and.. thats the thing.. im not sure how..

Comment: You can add them in Payment table also if you want but you need to be sure that one row in POSSales also has a single equivalent row in Payment. If in a scenario when there is 1 POSSales row that has 2 or more Payment row, you may have to update the 2 or more rows in Payment instead of updating just one in POSSales.

Comment: reason why i think to add new row in Payment is that.. in report.. i want to show the transaction details and the cancellation details.. meaning.. for example if i cancel POSID = 360, so there will be 2 data for POSID = 360. One is for the original transaction and 2nd is the cancelled transactions.. I meant, why should add/update data in POSSales? if you can explain or give example how the data will look like? very much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: i also need to update the inventory as well for cancelled items.. to add back the cancelled items in the inventory.. hmmm.. right now if i want to know how many items sales.. i will read from POSSales and link to POSDetails and compare with items inventory in order to trace missing items or shud i create another table just to store cancelled POSSales?.. im still blurr.. -,-